# php array mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This foreach loop only inserts one (the last value in the array) record, the array contains about 20 values. Can someone please help I can;t seem to work this one out

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


 $sql = " INSERT INTO table3 (date, header, header2) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), '".$key."', '".$value."') " ;

 }
```

Comment: Because you don't have executed query inside the loop

Comment: You are overriding the $sql variable on every loop. Try using .=

Comment: because u r executing your query outside the loop, you need to execute query inside the loop

Comment: Technically, that loop doesn't insert _any_ records.

Comment: @IanS In that case, it will require a semicolon at the end of each mysql statement

Comment: These loop dose not contain anything that inserts records. Run the query using `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {


 $sql = " INSERT INTO table3 (date, header, header2) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), '".$key."', '".$value."') " ;
 $sqlquery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); //$conn is your connection variable 
 }
```

Comment: but you can optimize it, you can use one query instead of multiple @spyda46

Comment: don't forget to accept answer if its helpful for you. :)

Comment: its an example of that what he miss in his code. :)

Comment: the only problem I am still having is the end value, is inserted twice - any ideas ?

Comment: @spyda46 remember to remove your sql-execution after the loop. Thats probably why it inserts the last one twice. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because you only define $sql, which is just a string, but don't actually execute the sql-statement.

You have to move the execution of your sql-statement into the loop for this to work.

e.g.:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

 $sql = " INSERT INTO table3 (date, header, header2) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE(), '".$key."', '".$value."') " ;
 $mysqli->query($sql);

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this optimized way as it will reduce your database operation and boost execution speed..

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO table3 (date, header, header2) VALUES ";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 $sql .= "(`".CURRENT_DATE()"`, `".$key."`, `".$value."`),";
}
$sql = trim($sql ,',');
$mysqli->query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: best way, execute query at once.

Comment: this gives me -- PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH

Comment: try to get it to work, but the above gives -- PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING